# Pushing arrays in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

If I have a nested array

```
\def\yeet{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}
```

How do I add another array to "yeet"

E.g.

I have yeet: {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}
and I have feet: {7,8,9}
I want to add feet to yeet so I get

```
yeet: {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}
```

Furthermore, I would like to add elements to arrays

so I have array keet: {3,6} and I want to add integer 9 to keet so I get

```
keet: {3,6,9}
```

Lastly, I need to be able to clear the array so if I have

```
yeet: {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}
```

and I want to delete all elements of yeet I should get

```
yeet: {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\def\yeet{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}
\typeout{\yeet}"\yeet"

\appto\yeet{,{3,6,9}}
\typeout{\yeet}"\yeet"

\def\yeet{}
\typeout{\yeet}"\yeet"
\end{document}
```

Comment: I hate to be a pain. I would much prefer not to use third party libraries since I can't do that with the bot I am using. I can use all \usetikzlibrary

Comment: @OllyEatough You can use `\edef\yeet{\yeet,{3,6,9}}` instead of `\appto\yeet{,{3,6,9}}`. Be aware, however, that `etoolbox` offers a lot of really cool functions, it is very likely that you will need them one day. They can be used in perfect harmony with Ti*k*Z and are really useful when you do not want to expand things when appending stuff, when you mess around with ampersands and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot man :D

Comment: Okay so I tried this
```
,tex
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\yeet{0,1}
\edef\yeet{\yeet,{1,2}}
\draw (0,0)--(1,1);
\draw (\yeet[0],\yeet[1])--(\yeet[2],\yeet[3]);
\end{tikzpicture}
```
And got an error: ! Package PGF Math Error: Array index out of bounds. (in '{1,2}[2]').

Comment: It is not unusual if one gets error messages from an incorrect usage of the syntax. Try `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture} 
 \def\yeet{0,1} 
 \edef\yeet{{\yeet},{1,2}} 
 \draw (0,0)--(1,1); 
 \draw ({{\yeet}[0][0]},{{\yeet}[0][1]})--({{\yeet}[1][0]},{{\yeet}[1][1]}); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`.